# Unbound module graphics in ocaml

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I'm using ocaml toplevel and used:

```
#load "graphics.cma";;
```

The library got loaded, but when I'm trying:

```
open Graphics;;
```

I'm getting unbounded module Graphics error.
I used #list to list all packages and "graphics" was there in the list.
I have seen all related answers but still don't get why I'm getting this
error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what symbol `**` means in your code snippet, whether you tried to use some sort of markup, or not, but this symbols shouldn't be there:

```
# #load "graphics.cma";;
# open Graphics;;
# open_graph "";;
- : unit = ()
#
```

Make sure that you literally input this directive (`#`-including): `#load "graphics.cma";;`

If this still doesn't work, you can try `#require "graphics";;`. This is, by the way, a preferred way to load libraries and packages in modern OCaml.

Comment: I didn't intend to put **. I tried the same code. It's loading the graphics cma file, but on using `open Graphics;;`, it's giving me unbound module error.

Comment: I also tried `#require "graphics";;`, it printed /usr/lib/ocaml/graphics.cma: loaded on the terminal and when i used `open Graphics;;` it gave me the same error

Comment: looks like your installation is broken. How did you install OCaml, what operating system are you using?

Comment: i'm on ubuntu 12.04. I installed ocaml initially from apt-get. Then uninstalled it and used OPAM to get the latest version.

Comment: should i remove everything and start fresh? If so, how should I do that so this problem doesn't come again?

Comment: if you're using `opam`, then make sure that you didn't forget to activate environment with `eval $(opam config env)` command. I suspect, that you're accidentally running semi-deleted ocaml from ubuntu.